# Use .clasp.json to associate git repo with Apps Script project

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I'd like to use [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) to develop Apps Script projects locally. Clasp has a built-in clone method which fetches a project by ID and pulls the code into a local directory. This also creates a `.clasp.json` file with some project settings.

The problem is that my code is already in a Git repo, so I'm wondering what the best method of getting the code locally would be. Is there a difference between these two methods?

- Clone with `git` and then edit `.clasp.json` to point to the correct project id
- Clone with `clasp` and then `git init` a repo and manually set the remote URL

...or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two methods would work in the same fashion. They will both work and there is no different between them.

However, this is a matter of taste and comfort rather than best-practice. In my opinion, the best method is the first one.